# Where do I add subviews to a custom UIView so it will show up when created in IB and programmatically, and also rendered in IB?

Tags: ios, uiview, interface-builder, ios8, xcode6

When creating a custom `UIView` where (in terms of a method) should I be adding subviews and other initialization steps so that it shows up when:

- Gets created from being added in Interface Builder
- Gets created from being init'd and added programmatically
- Viewing in Interface Builder through the new `@IBDesignable` feature in Xcode 6

I'm very confused where I should be adding this. Say my view always needs to have a specific image embedded in it and then have the `UIImageView`'s corners rounded. What method should I be doing that in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit - Initially misunderstood the question...

You could override your custom UIView's vanilla `init` method and handle it there.

You could also declare a custom initializer to call in case you need to pass in arguments like the UIImageView.

In CustomView.h

```
-(CustomView *)initWithImage:(UIImage*)image;
```

In CustomView.m

```
-(CustomView *)initWithImage:(UIImage*)image 
{
    if (self = [super init]){
    //do whatever you need with rounded corners, setting images, etc
    }
    return self;  
}
```

For default images your custom view has to have a UIImageView subview in IB, and you can set the image there. To change it in code it has to be an IBOutlet).

As for rounded corners, pretty sure you have to do that in code - IB doesn't have that capability.

Haven't yet played around w/@IBDesignable.

Comment: `viewDidLoad` is not called on `UIView`s, just `UIViewController`s. Furthermore they're not rendered in IB.